# What is the definition of taxiing?

Tags: taxiing, ground-operations, terminology

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxiing) the definition of taxiing is:

> the movement of the aircraft on the ground **under its own power** [however]
>   push-back is **not** considered taxiing

In contrast, [Eurocontrol](http://www.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/lexicon/en/index.php/Actual_Taxi-Out_Time) seems to define it as:

> **any movement on the ground** including push-back

Any other reliable sources to look up for the correct definition?

Comment: I removed the request for an opinion, as that would be off-topic here.

Comment: @tcfx44 The link for EUROCONTROL's website you referenced does not provide the definition you mentioned.

Comment: Concerning the first definition: If neither movement under the aircraft's own power nor pushback count as taxiing, there isn't much left, or is there?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think you may have misread the first one, due to its somewhat awkward wording. He was saying that taxiing consists of moving on the ground under its own power and, therefore, push-back (which usually doesn't take place under the aircraft's own power) isn't considered taxiing.

Comment: Actually, your question will coming back to you. It depends on why do you ask the question you partly know the answer. If you are a pilot, then Wikipedia answer is enough. But if you are trying to write something on aviation, you probably should consider who is your target reader, and give them the most satisfiable definition.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You had to read the quote and its introduction as a single sentence ("taxiing is foo and bar is not taxiing") rather than reading the quote on its own ("foo and bar is not taxiing"). I edited the quote to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Definitions always depend on their context, that is why documents often included a list of definitions. It allows authors to define terms in the context of the document. A definition context is not always a document, it could for example be a field of expertise as well.

The Commercial Aviation Safety Team / International Civil Aviation Organization (CAST/ICAO) [Common Taxonomy Team](http://www.intlaviationstandards.org/index.html) (CICTT) [taxi is defined](http://www.intlaviationstandards.org/Glossary.html#P-T) as:

> The aircraft is moving on the aerodrome surface under its own power
>   prior to takeoff or  after landing

More detail can be found in the [phase of flight](http://www.intlaviationstandards.org/Documents/PhaseofFlightDefinitions.pdf) definition document. 
This is definition can be applied in many situations.

The Eurocontrol definition you link to comes from the Air Traffic Flow & Capacity  Management (ATFCM) and Airport Collaborative Decision Making (A-CDM) domains where statistics about gate-to-runway time play an important role for planning purposes.

In that context it is not really interesting to distinguish the time that was spend in pushback from the time spend actually taxiing to the runway. The taxi-out time is hence defined as the time between off-blocks and take-off.

Answer (score 7):

The FAA definition is in [14 CFR 135.100](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=32f12d30db9d9064cf53135b34a77a39&node=se14.3.135_1100&rgn=div8) and the [pilot/controller glossary](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/PCG.pdf) (quoted here):

> TAXI- The movement of an airplane under its own power on the surface
> of an airport (14 CFR Section 135.100 [Note]). Also, it describes the
> surface movement of helicopters equipped with wheels.

Interestingly, "pushback" is not in the glossary at all.

This matches the Wikipedia definition that you mentioned, although not the ICAO one from DeltaLima. I think this definition makes sense, because taxiing doesn't necessarily have to be before a takeoff or after a landing. It's possible that the aircraft is simply taxiing from one point to another on the airport surface, e.g. from the fuel pumps to the hangar. That might be more common in GA, though: when I see airliners repositioning on the ground they're usually being towed.

You also didn't mention air or hover taxiing, but I think it's fairly obvious in that case that the helicopter is under its own power. Here are the FAA definitions, for completeness, both from the [P/CG](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/PCG.pdf):

> AIR TAXI- Used to describe a helicopter/VTOL aircraft movement
> conducted above the surface but normally not above 100 feet AGL. The
> aircraft may proceed either via hover taxi or flight at speeds more
> than 20 knots. The pilot is solely responsible for selecting a safe
> airspeed/altitude for the operation being conducted.
>
> HOVER TAXI- Used to describe a helicopter/VTOL aircraft movement
> conducted above the surface and in ground effect at airspeeds less
> than approximately 20 knots. The actual height may vary, and some
> helicopters may require hover taxi above 25 feet AGL to reduce ground
> effect turbulence or provide clearance for cargo slingloads.

Comment: "Helicopters equipped with wheels" -- really?

Comment: Yes, really: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:UH-60A_Black_Hawk.jpg

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Didn't you see [Airwolf](http://www.rcphenom.com/RC%20Phenom/Heli/Airwolf1.jpg)?

Comment: Air wolf! Of course.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Really. *Many* helicopters are equipped with wheels rather than skids. (The Boeing Chinook was the first example that came to my mind; other examples include military helicopters designed for launch from ships: it's much easier to wheel the helicopter into the hangar than anything else.)

Answer (score 1):

> any movement on the ground including push-back

This definition of taxiing is more specific to controllers. Once the aircraft has commenced its pushback it is normally infringing a controlled movement area and will be under the control of the ground or tower controller.

> the movement of the aircraft on the ground under its own power and
>   push-back is not considered taxiing

I believe this to be the more correct definition. Movement of an aircraft under its own power is important in a regulatory sense for aircraft operators. There are a number of matching definitions, relating to compliance with the Minimum Equipment List(MEL), ETOPs despatch - relating to weather minima and the definition of a sector, which is important for calculating the allowable flight duty period(FDP).

- Definition of ETOPs Dispatch:

[Extended range Twin Operations](http://easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Annex%20II%20-%20AMC%2020-6.pdf)

> Dispatch
>   Dispatch is when the aircraft first moves under its own power for the purpose of taking-off.

Dispatch is also used in relation to an aircraft meeting the requirements of the Minimum Equipment List (MEL) for a "flight"(defined below).

- Definition of Sector
  [UK CAP371 Flight Time Limitations](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP371.PDF)

> 'Sector'
>   The time between an aircraft first moving under its own power until it next comes to rest after landing, on the designated parking position.

- Flight

[Definition of Flight - ref to MEL](http://www.jaa.nl/secured/Operations/OPS%20NAA/02%20Special%20Information/NPA%20MMELMEL-2.doc)

> "Commencement of flight" The point when an aircraft begins to move under its own power for the purpose of preparing for take off.

Answer (score -1):

The time you leave the apron (GATE/RAMP position) and arrived at your takeoff strip (Piano key-marked Takeoff zone), the journey in between is well-known as taxiing. I am sure that this is correct because I have experience with runways and aircrafts. It's a common sense that taxii means no ground power/air cart, and also no support. You taxi your way to the takeoff zone. No disupte about this.

Comment: Please give a citation. The personal experience of an anonymous stranger on the internet isn't worth a lot because we have no way of evaluating whether your experience is typical or whether you're interpreting it correctly.